# Not getting updated value from useState when accessing it from an event listener

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

`sound` object is null after invoking event `onStopButtonPress` although I invoked that event after `onPlayButtonPress` event, so it has to have a value, but it is null

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import Sound from "react-native-sound";
import PlayIcon from "../svg/PlayIcon";
import StopIcon from "../svg/StopIcon";
import { scale } from "react-native-utils-scale";

const PlayAudioButton = (props) => {
  const { url, action, playingId, setPlayingId } = props;
  const [sound, setSound] = useState(null);
  console.log("Sound object: ", sound)

  const onPlayButtonPress = () => {
    setPlayingId(url);
    const fullUrl = `${url?.startsWith("/") ? url?.slice(1) : url}`;
    const newSound = new Sound(fullUrl, "", (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Error loading sound", error);
      } else {
        console.log("Audio Started");
        newSound.play(() => {
          newSound.release();
          setPlayingId(null);
          console.log("Audio stopped")
        });
      }
    });
    setSound(newSound)
  };

  const onStopButtonPress = () => {
    setPlayingId(null);
    if (sound) {
      sound.stop();
      sound.release();
    }
  };

  return (
      <View
          style={{
            justifyContent: "center",
            paddingHorizontal: scale(4),
          }}
      >
        {(url !== playingId || playingId === null) ? (
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                  flex: 1,
                  justifyContent: "center",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  alignSelf: "stretch",
                  zIndex: 3,
                }}
                onPress={() => {
                  onPlayButtonPress();
                  action ? action() : null;
                }}
            >
              <PlayIcon color="#011132" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ) : (
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                  flex: 1,
                  justifyContent: "center",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  alignSelf: "stretch",
                  zIndex: 3,
                }}
                onPress={() => {
                  onStopButtonPress();
                  action ? action() : null;
                }}
            >
              <StopIcon color="#c79546" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      </View>
  );
};

export default PlayAudioButton;
```

I tried using useState, useEffect, useRef but all failed

Comment: you code is fine i try it with expo-av perhabs the issue come from the react-native-sound that stack when initialize the sound object but if the sound work correctly for you  then try to setSound inside new Sound(...)  :     const newSound = new Sound(fullUrl, "", (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Error sound", error);
      } else {
        console.log("Audio Started");
       setSound(newSound); 
        newSound.play(() => {
          newSound.release();
          setPlayingId(null);
          console.log("Audio stopped")
        });
         
      }
    });

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use `state` while you dont need to re-render screen using any Sound value, just use `useRef` to avoid re-render:

like this:

```
   const soundRef = useRef()
    
   const onPlayButtonPress = () => {
    setPlayingId(url);
    const fullUrl = `${url?.startsWith("/") ? url?.slice(1) : url}`;
    const newSound = new Sound(fullUrl, "", (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Error loading sound", error);
      } else {
        console.log("Audio Started");
        newSound.play(() => {
          newSound.release();
          soundRef.current = null
          setPlayingId(null);
          console.log("Audio stopped")
        });
      }
    });
    soundRef.current = newSound
  };

  const onStopButtonPress = () => {
    setPlayingId(null);
      soundRef.current?.stop();
      soundRef.current?.release();
  };
```